# Tailwind Border

Tags: css, user-interface, user-experience

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB4I9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWvql.png)I'm trying to designed this card in tailwind but I've got a problem to design highlight on the border how can I design highlights in tailwind or css

there is nothing to look up for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create this effect with :after or :before and use this style in tailwind for generating the gradient

```
@apply bg-[radial-gradient(closest-side,white,transparent)]
```

[Live example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lgUCf1llhf?file=css)